# Open REST API attached to a database- what stops a bad actor spamming my db?

Tags: rest, http, web, server, crud

I'm a client side developer with little experience of server side, and I'm struggling to understand how to make a database-backed website without requiring users to login.

The usecase is fairly straightforward. The user lands on a website, uploads an image, and performs some processing to that image. Clicking 'share' POSTs JSON to my endpoint, stores it in a DB, and returns a unique URL in a textbox (eg, https://example.com/art/12345) which allows the user to share their artwork with others, or just to come back and do more editing later on.

What stops somebody from doing, `POST <data> https://example.com/art` 100 million times and filling my pay-as-you-go database?

I've seen examples of this link based method of sharing between users on plenty of sites but I don't understand how to stop abuse, or whether it is safe to just open up an API which allows writes to a database. I do not want users to have to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the simplest method is having a quota, either by username for logged in users or by IP, if you don't require logins or only want to allow free usage to a certain point.   Perhaps you could have a smaller quota for non-logged in users than for logged in users and even larger for paying users.

Your server side code that handles the POSTS and storing data into the database would have to take care of that.  I'd add it to a user_data table on mine, making an additional column that tracks total space used.   *makes a todo*

Then, when the user adds new data, increase the total space used.   When they delete old data (I have versioned web pages so that eventually, the user will be able to rollback to previous versions) then the space used decreases.  Having another page to look at to see where they're using space makes deciding what to delete to stay under a quota of X MB's/GB's/TB's/etc easier or maybe just an /api/delete_old_pages or notes or comments or all of the above.

Comment: I had been hoping to use a DBaaS, so hopefully some of them offer rate throttling by IP